# TVS ESD diode power rating

Tags: esd, tvs

Is there any rule on how to choose the power rating of a bi-directional TVS diode which will be used in automotive 12V system as an ESD protection?

They range from 20-40W all the way to 1000W and more, how to choose the right one?

Comment: I suspect that you are referring to the peak-pulse-power rating of TVS diodes, which describes the maximum instanteneous power it is designed to withstand.

Comment: You are right. How to choose according to peak-pulse-power rating?

Comment: I am no expert on this; my understanding is that you must first have a specification of how big surges/impulses you expect on your input, which I assume heavily depends on the system/car you are plugging this into.